# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file after updating android studio

Tags: android, gradle

My project was compiling fine before updating the android studio. But after i updated android studio to v3.5 i can't compile my project. I am getting following error:

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72945 > 65536)
```

I can't even change a single line code.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def retrofitVersion = "2.5.0"

    def supportVersion = '1.0.0-beta01'
    def glideVersion = "4.8.0"

    def rxjava_version = '2.2.8'
    def rxandroid_version = '2.1.1'

    def dagger_version = "2.19"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0"


    def lifecycle_version = '2.1.0-alpha04'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$supportVersion"

    def reactivestreams_version = '2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$reactivestreams_version"

    def rxcalladapter_version = '2.5.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rxcalladapter_version"

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:$glideVersion") {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'


    def room_version = '2.1.0-alpha07'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    // RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"

    // RxAndroid
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-beta01'

    // Dagger

//    def dagger_version = "2.16" // version used by google samples

    // Dagger2 core
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    // Dagger Android
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'


    //Camera library
    implementation 'com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11'
    implementation 'com.camerakit:jpegkit:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'

    //Image Picker
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:2.0.0'

    //Audio recorder
    def audio_recorder_version = "1.6.0"
    implementation "com.github.piasy:rxandroidaudio:$audio_recorder_version"
    implementation "com.github.piasy:AudioProcessor:$audio_recorder_version"
    implementation 'com.hhl:gridpagersnaphelper:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.hhl:recyclerviewindicator:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ahmadmuzakki29:subtitle-collapsingtoolbar:v2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.3.0'

    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
}
```

I researched on stackoverflow for dex file errors, some people says "enabling instant run resolved the issue for me" I suspected about instant run because they have changed the instant run mechanism and removed instant run settings from android studio. Maybe this is the problem?

How can i resolve this problem without enabling multiDex support?

Comment: **JRE** by default supports `65536 methods` limit. I suggest you try `minifyEnabled true` for all build types that can help strip out unused methods and classes. Also enable R8 which is hell lot of faster than old proguard. Try to remove unused 3rd party dependencies from gradle if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay away from `multiDex` you have two options. Actually one option, the other one is just crippled form of the main option. By the way, I just copy-pasted all your `gradle` file and tested it.

> **Option 1. (Recommended)**

**Step 1.** Create a `proguard` file for your debug. Let's say `debug-proguard-rules.pro` and add the following line to your debug proguard file. This line will force the compiler to keep classes and class memebers' names as-is during debug build which is quite helpful:

```
-dontobfuscate
```

**Step 2.** Add `debug` build type to your gradle. This will apply `proguard` rules from both `proguard-rules.pro` and `proguard-rules-debug.pro` files.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

> **Option 2.**

If you don't care about your classes and class members being obfuscated in `debug` build, then just add the following line to your `build types`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
    release {
        //........
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well this is unusual that you don't want to enable multidex - in this case it is the best option. However there are more options to do it relatively easy:

- change `minSdkVersion` from `19` to `21` - this way the runtime have to be able to handle 65k limit by itself. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l)
- change `minifyEnabled` from `false` to `true` - if you got lucky proguard or r8 will shrink your project enough to fit into 65k. This way you may need to create a file with minifying rules though. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#avoid)
- add `{
  transitive = false;
  }` to all the dependencies you can - and hope all the needed ones are present in your project, instead of those inner ones that you ignore with this command. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#avoid)

Also you can try to manipulate with the gradle build config to shrink classes manually but it is not very good idea since for different versions of gradle you may need a different approach(since deprecation, new API, etc.). Also this way you may delete too much and receive a nightmare of debug in future.

Hope it will help you somehow.

Comment: "what can  I say, except that I am thankfuuul?" (Moama (c) style music)

Answer (score 0):

Without Multidex, we will have to strip unused libraries.

Please add following to the bottom of your app/build.gradle file

```
def toCamelCase(String string) {
    String result = ""
    string.findAll("[^\\W]+") { String word ->
        result += word.capitalize()
    }
    return result
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    Configuration runtimeConfiguration = project.configurations.getByName('compile')
    ResolutionResult resolution = runtimeConfiguration.incoming.resolutionResult
    // Forces resolve of configuration
    ModuleVersionIdentifier module = resolution.getAllComponents().find { it.moduleVersion.name.equals("play-services") }.moduleVersion

    String prepareTaskName = "prepare${toCamelCase("${module.group} ${module.name} ${module.version}")}Library"
    File playServiceRootFolder = project.tasks.find { it.name.equals(prepareTaskName) }.explodedDir

    Task stripPlayServices = project.tasks.create(name: 'stripPlayServices', group: "Strip") {
        inputs.files new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")
        outputs.dir playServiceRootFolder
        description 'Strip useless packages from Google Play Services library to avoid reaching dex limit'

        doLast {
            copy {
                from(file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")))
                into(file(playServiceRootFolder))
                rename { fileName ->
                    fileName = "classes_orig.jar"
                }
            }
            tasks.create(name: "stripPlayServices" + module.version, type: Jar) {
                destinationDir = playServiceRootFolder
                archiveName = "classes.jar"
                from(zipTree(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar"))) {
                    exclude "com/google/ads/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/analytics/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/games/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/plus/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/drive/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/ads/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/wallet/**"
                    exclude "com/google/android/gms/wearable/**"
                }
            }.execute()
            delete file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar"))
        }
    }

    project.tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('prepare') && it.name.endsWith('Dependencies') }.each { Task task ->
        task.dependsOn stripPlayServices
    }
}
```

In this example, we are stripping analytics, games, plus, drive, ads, wallet, wearable codes and functions.
You should manually add libraries/packages you don't need. So, that, overall function count is within 64K limit.

Another approach is to use this library (old): https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex

Comment: I am getting Cannot get property 'moduleVersion' on null object

Answer (score -1):

Modify the app/build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Details can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I said: "How can i resolve this problem without enabling multiDex support?"